# Compilation Error with C++ core libraries

Tags: c++, compilation

During compilation of a software I am consistently receiving the following error messages.

PasteBin Link: http://pastebin.com/TmHKqey2

I have tried the solutions on forums that discussed similar issues: changing all makefiles from makefile.* to Makefile.*; updating the headers etc - but no success.

Any suggestions/insights?

Thanks!

```
$ make
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c AddNode.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c CTableGen.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c CorrectionTable.c
CorrectionTable.c: In function ‘CorrectionTableInit’:
CorrectionTable.c:590: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
CorrectionTable.c:623: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c Decomp.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c DLBfreeOld.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c FMComm.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c FMSigma2.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c FMSupport.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c FreeInitArrays.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c GetNewNativeNode.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c Heap.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c InitCellDomains.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c InitCellNatives.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c InitCellNeighbors.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c InitSendDomains.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c InitRemoteDomains.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c MemCheck.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c Meminfo.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c Param.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c Parse.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c QueueOps.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c RBDecomp.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c RSDecomp.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c ReadRestart.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c Timer.c
colorgcc -O -DLONGDOUBLE   -I ../include -c Util.c
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:34,
                 from Util.c:119:
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include/stddef.h:211: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘typedef’
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:75,
                 from Util.c:119:
/usr/include/libio.h:332: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘size_t’
/usr/include/libio.h:364: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
/usr/include/libio.h:373: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’
```

[Updated: Added initial parts of make output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually get this if I have an error before the included file. So I would look in Util.c before the include of stdio.h to see if there is some syntax error. The error could be in some include that you've included before stdio.h.

Most common cause, missing ';' or '}'.